# Passing data to next view controller with modal segue

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have tried to use modal segue in Storyboard to push user data from didSelectRowAtIndexPath and send it to next View Controller .

Here is my code :

In my header file  :

```
@interface ListNearby : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UINavigationBarDelegate>

{
   @public
   UserDetails *UD;
}
```

And my .m file  :

```
ResultNearbyList *cell = (ResultNearbyList *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

self.userFullNameString = cell.userFullName.text;

NSLog(@"FulluserName NextVC = %@",self.userFullNameString);

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sendUserData" sender:self];
```

And I am preparing segue to pass data to next view controller :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sendUserData"]) {

        UD = (UserDetails *) segue.destinationViewController;

        UD.userFullName.text = self.userFullNameString;

        NSLog(@"FulluserName Segue = %@",UD.userFullName.text);

        NSLog(@"FulluserName Current = %@",self.userFullNameString);

    }
}
```

Segue , showing NextViewController without any problem. The problem is userFullNameString does not sending to NextViewController. I am checking with NSLog , while FulluserName Segue returning null, FulluserName Current returning value that i need.

How can i send that data to the next view controller ?

regards..

Comment: What is `userFullName`?

Comment: it's a string that i need to pass it in to next view controller

Comment: try to declare a property  `@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *userFulName`  in the `UserDetails.h` file and in your prepare for segue method `UD.userFulName = self.userFullNameString;` then in the `viewDidLoad` of your next view controller(i.e. UserDetails) `userFullName.text = userFulName;` try this out

Comment: U made my night @ArunKumar , Thank you so much, in stack, all problems about pushing segue and no detail about modal segue to pass data and handle. Thank you so much ...

Comment: glad that i could help you . so i am writing down the answer plz accept

Comment: Please write. I will accept gladly !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare a property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *userFulName;
```

in the `UserDetails.h` file. In your prepare for segue method

```
UD.userFulName = self.userFullNameString;
```

then in the `viewDidLoad` of your next view controller(i.e. UserDetails)

```
userFullName.text = userFulName;
```

Comment: So it means , data cannot pass to UI object . First we need to assing it to next view controller's Non UI element than in viewload, assing it to UILabel.text for example  ...

Comment: we cannot set the string value in a label in another viewcontroller directly within a segue method. For that we need to create a NSString object that will pass the values to the UILabel objects when the segue will be performed.